# SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing (python)

Tags: python

Учусь писать код, создал программму Space Bank, чтобы улучшать ее по мере изученного, непонятная мне ошибка

> SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

пишу на Python (VS code)

Мой код:

```
import re

def checkNumber():
    number = (input('Enter your phone number: '))
    
    if re.match(r'[\+7|8]?.?(\d{3}).?(\d{3}).?(\d{2}).?(\d{2})', number) and len(number) <= 12 or re.match(r'^\w+[\.]?(\w+)*\@(\w+\.)*\w{2,}$', number):
        return number
    else:
        checkNumber()

def checkEmail():
    email = (input('Enter email'))
    
    if re.match(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,100}[@][a-z]{2,6}\.[a-z]{2,4}'):
        return email
    else:
        checkEmail()
        
class Registration():
    def __init__(self, name, surname, number, email, password):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.number = number
        self.email = email
        self.password = password

userinfo = Registration((input('Enter your name: '), (input('Enter your last name: ')), checkNumber(), checkEmail(), (input('Enter your password: '))
```

Comment: В самой последней строке у вас полный бардак со скобочками

Answer (score 1):

1. В конце строки

```
userinfo = Registration((input('Enter your name: '), (input('Enter your last name: ')), checkNumber(), checkEmail(), (input('Enter your password: '))))
                                                                                                                                                    #^^ здесь пропущены скобки
```

вы пропустили закрывающиеся скобки.

*Лучше уберите лишние скобки перед и после `input` и напишите так:*

```
userinfo = Registration(input('Enter your name: '), input('Enter your last name: '), checkNumber(), checkEmail(), input('Enter your password: '))
```

---

2. `email = (input('Enter email'))` замените на `email = (input('Enter email: '))`

---

3. В `if re.match(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,100}[@][a-z]{2,6}\.[a-z]{2,4}'):` отсутствует обязательный аргумент `string`, то есть напишите так: `if re.match(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,100}[@][a-z]{2,6}\.[a-z]{2,4}', email):`

---

4. В `if re.match(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,100}[@][a-z]{2,6}\.[a-z]{2,4}', email):` не проходит *email*, который я ввожу. Думаю вы напутали в условии.